# Compare elements in two lists and make a new List

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

From two lists , make a new list, by comparing their i th position. I can do it using loop but can't do using list comprehension

my code:

```
List1=[1,2,7,8]
List2=[3,4,5,6]
List3=[]
for i in range(len(List1)):
if(List1[i]>List2[i]):
   List3.append(List1[i])
else:
    List3.append(List2[i])

print(List3)
```

Desired output:[3,4,7,8]

Comment: `[max(x) for x in zip(l1,l2)]`

Answer (score 1):

Use zip:

```
List3 = [max(x) for x in zip(List1, List2)]
```

Comment: Thanks , this is helpful